# How to use Angular service in component to post form data to api

Tags: angular

I have a form in Angular 6, I also have a service written to get and post requests to a web api. I can get the requests fine. But I am struggling to post my data from my form to the api. The code I have does not work. So far I have:

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicenowService {

  serviceApiUrl: string = 'api/incident';


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,

  ) { }

  getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceApiUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  getIncidents(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.serviceApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  postIncidents(customerId): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.serviceApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId, null)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something has wrong; Api is not working!'));
  };

}
```

**form.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Request } from '../../models/request.model'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppComponent } from '../../../app.component';
import { ServicenowService } from '../../services/servicenow.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse,} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-service-request',
  templateUrl: './service-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-request.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  public customers;
  public customer;

  private customer_id = 7; /// this.appComponent.customer_id;

  serviceForm;

  countries = [
    { name: 'Choose an option' },
    { name: 'United Kingdom', },
    { name: 'United States of America', },
    { name: 'Russia', },
    { name: 'Moscow', },
    { name: 'Africa', },
  ];

  users = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  devices = [
    { id: 'Select an option', },
    { id: '1', },
    { id: '2', },
    { id: '3', },
  ];

  constructor(private service: ServicenowService,
    private appComponent : AppComponent,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient

  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm = new FormGroup({
      u_caller_id: new FormControl(this.users[0], Validators.required),
      u_cmdb_ci: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_destination_country: new FormControl(this.countries[0], Validators.required),
      u_requester_phone_number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      u_serial_number: new FormControl(this.devices[0], Validators.required),
      subject: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(10)
      ])),
      issue: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    var data = "u_cmdb_ci=" + this.serviceForm.value.u_cmdb_ci;
    this.service.postIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {});
    console.log("data has gone");
       }
  }
```

I have injected the service into the component but its does not work I have also tried the following, I know its only one field but I wanted to just test it but not working:

```
onSubmit() {
    var data = "u_cmdb_ci=" + this.serviceForm.value.u_cmdb_ci;
    this.http.post("api/incident", data).subscribe((res) => {});
    console.log("data has gone");
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what "does not work" mean. If you open your Browser's developer tools, can you see the network call to the API? Is the call being made to the correct endpoint? If you use curl or wget or a tool like postman to call that same URL, does that work?

Comment: I get 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Comment: Also Cannot read property 'ngOriginalError' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You should be posting your object through, not trying to turn it into a URL param. Additionally add in an error handler so you can get some error data to solve any issues.

```
onSubmit() {
    var data = this.serviceForm.value.u_cmdb_ci;
    this.http.post("api/incident", data).subscribe(
       (res) => {
          console.log(res);
       },
       (error) => {
          console.log(error);
       }
    );
    console.log("data has gone");
}
```